# ng toolkit and angular - what to upload to server

Tags: angular

I am using ng toolkit for angular SEO.
It works Ok locally but I don't understand which files I need to upload to server and why.

I ran those commands:

```
ng add @ng-toolkit/universal
npm run build:prod;npm run server
```

now the source of `http://localhost:8080` is SEO friendly.

dist folder looks like this:

```
browser folder (include index.html, assets, etc)
server folder (include only files: main.js and main.js.map)
file server.js
```

What I need to upload to my host server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload `index.html` and all the files inside that folder

Comment: so I need to upload only the content of the 'browser' folder? so how does it solve the SEO issue?

Comment: Angular build the web as an minified application. If you want full SEO friendly web page you should use server side rendering. https://angular.io/guide/universal

Comment: sorry, I think you don't understand my question. It is already SEO friendly but I don't sure which files I need to upload to me host server. I used this tutorial: https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-seo-making-angular-6-single-page-web-apps-search-engine-friendly-c8ec4ff2f549

Comment: I see. Then it is time to ask you,  what version of Angular you are using?

Comment: angular version 7

Comment: when running locally using 'npm run server', the web source is SEO friendly

Comment: You need Server Side Rendering and you should be using this command ```npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr```